# Is there a way of getting selected option on ng2-materialize autocomplete using angular 4.x?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have done ng2-materialize autocomplete and it's working accordingly the problem i have is that i can't get selected option from the filtered list without clicking any button.

Typescript

```
autocomplete: { data: { [key: string]: string }};
this.autocomplete = { data : {"Exaple 1":null,"Example 2":null,"Example 3":null}};

<mz-input-container>           
<input mz-input type='text' id="autocomplete" [placeholder]="'Enter to filter'" class="autocomplete" [autocomplete]="autocomplete"/>
</mz-input-container>
```

Comment: If you require help with code please start with an [mcve]. I recommend you use https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @Igor thanks, please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzq28u.